# OpenSuse15 -> iptables -> geoip "No chain/target/match by that name."

Tags: iptables, opensuse

Hi I use OpenSuse Leap 15 with xtables-addons installed.

If I want to only allow incoming connections at port 22/tcp from Germany. I tied this command:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m geoip ! --source-country DE -j DROP`

And I get this Error message:
`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name`

This screenshot shows my current configuration:
[image]

In [this forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195565) I have read that you also need a linux kernel module `xt_geoip`. If I run the command `modprobe xt_geoip`

I get `FATAL: Module xt_geoip not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.104-39-default`

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade to an older kernel to fix this.

Check if your OpenSUSE Leap15 installation has a version mismatch of the packages kernel-default and xtables-addons-kmp-default.

If the versions match, the xt_geoip module should be listed in the current /lib/modules/*-default/extra directory. If not then choose an older package of kernel-default with the same version and boot with that kernel.

Answer (score -1):

Silly question, but is that module xt_geoip actually found in that directory it's looking for the plugin at(/lib/modules/4.4.104-39-default)?

You may need to just link it if the module didn't install there, or add the path to /etc/modules if that module is in some other path, like shown in this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225845/how-do-i-configure-modprobe-to-find-my-module

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment asking for more information?

Comment: Both, an answer is provided in the link that it could be a simple need to load the module, and a question for more information if do they actually see it listed in the directory it saying it's looking for the module at.

The whole error right now is it can't load the module because it can't find it.